# Use async / await in TypeScript targeting ES5

Tags: javascript, typescript, async-await, ecmascript-5

I have a typescript project that's targeting ES5 and I am trying to determine whether or not it will be possible to use async / await.

Syntatically, the Typescript compiler will transpile the code just fine however I understand that I must provide a polyfill for 'Promise' since the object does not exist in ES5.

I am trying to use the npm 'promise' package for this, but I am encountering the following error when I include it in the same file where I have an 'async / await' function:

Duplicate identifier 'Promise'. Compiler reserves name 'Promise' in top level scope of a module containing async functions.

Therefore, I'm not sure how I can provide the 'Promise' functionality so that the code does not error at runtime.

Any workarounds for this? Thanks!

Comment: Did you try to `import` it or what? No, you should just load it as a polyfill when bundling/building for release, the compiler should not even see the library.

Comment: But without seeing your code (structure) and your configuration, it's really hard to help.

Comment: Just to follow up, this was for a library (ie, npm module) that I was told needed to be isomorphic. now, I'm being told that it doesn't need to work on the client - just on the server (consumed by Node app) so the polyfill is no longer necessary as Promise is available in the Node runtime. 

@Bergi - thanks for your input I believe that is the correct answer had I needed to go through with providing the polyfill.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on node.js, I recommend using ts-node. If you're developing with React, try scaffolding a starter with Create-React-App. Not sure about Angular. Instead of trying to put together your own transpiler config, these are better options that work out of the box.